# Azure Search and Azure Blob Storage: do you have to index all custom metadata items to search/filter them?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm setting up Azure Search to query metadata based on what a user sends in.

Do you HAVE to index all metadata items in Azure Blob Storage to be able to search/filter them?

Example:

I might save 5 items "custom" metadata:

AppFileId
AppLocation
AppDepartment
AppCost
AppTypeId

I would like to setup a call where I can query based on any of those or just one.

My question is:

Do all of them have to be indexed on this page on the Azure portal before I can search/filter against them?

I was hoping that I could just put any metadata property in my file and then obtain the file by querying off one metadata property or multiple. I know I need to use Azure Search Service.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about what "query off of it" mean.

As you said you would like to setup a call where you can query based on **any** of those **or just one**, obviously just index one metadata might cause problem when you need to query "any". So you need index all of the five custom metadata.

Comment: I updated the initial post. I was hoping you could pull back the file based on passing in one metadata item or multiple ones. I was hoping you did not have to index all 5, but it appears you do! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, good luck with Azure Search. @ttaylor27272727